# APK Woring fine on some devices but NOT in others

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I recently developed an Android application that shows at the first page a list of data that is stored in the database. And a button that allows the user to add data to the server and then add it automatically to the list. I generated an APK and install it in 3 devices it worked fine on two of them ( showing data and adding data) but in one mobile device "Oneplus A5010" it doesn't connect to the server. The code I think is fine because the same APK worked in the other devices. How can I fix that problem? And what may be the cause? 
PS: I am using JSON Volley library to get and post data to the server.

Comment: Check the logs, or post the logs here, that will help debug the problem.

Comment: Connect your device to your Android Studio and try running the app and log its run in logcat and share it here.

Comment: I discovered that it desn't run only in Android 9.0 Pie (latest version of android)

Comment: Thank you guys i found that the problem was android version problem